# How to warrant that binaries belong to source code?

Tags: security, compilation, packaging

I have a software which code is available online. I want to make that the end user has no doubt that the compiled binary that's  available online belongs to that code.

What options could exist to accomplish that? Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the online copy is trusted (e.g. it's your private github and you trust github), otherwise there's no point in users comparing binaries against the online copy.

I'm also assuming that you're the one building the official binaries, otherwise there's no guarantee that they were produced by a trustworthy processes.

Under those assumptions, you can compute the sha256 of the binaries, and tag the revision from which they were built with the hashes.

Users can then hash the binaries and compare them to the tags.